# can we split the dataset in k means into testing and training?

Tags: python, numpy

hi am working on a project which is detecting heart failure and now I want to use the k_means algorithm for clustering and SVM for classification.
I need to know if I can split the dataset into training and testing? since am using k_means is it ok??
please help...thanks

Comment: Please read [ask]. Much more context is needed to make this question understandable. What dataset are you talking about? What library is providing the k-means algorithm, and *what does the documentation say* about what to do with the dataset?

Comment: Additional question, you are using k-means for clustering, but how are you using SVM for classification after that? Are you using them sequentially (one after the other) by using cluster numbers as IDs? Or you are running Kmeans and SVM independently?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cut randomly in two sets. You can cut in sequential sets. You can cut in large temporally-adjacent tests. That is what the ANOVA tests are all about.